# Hubspot(CRM) datawarehouse

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, dimension, hubspot, fact

I am planning to create a datawarehouse for Hubspot CRM sourced data. I'm pulling Contracts,Contacts,Deals,Students tables data from Hubspot CRM tool.Is anybody having any idea on this. How to create facts and dimension table schema input on tables?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO, please read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to export Object data (Contact, Company, Deals and Tickets)from HubSpot, you might be interested in API.
Here is the link for the documentation.
https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/understanding-the-crm

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)